# How to prevent android browser keybord from switching to default on input value changed by js?

Tags: android, keyboard, maskedinput

I'm using Masked Input plugin for jQuery (Version: 1.3.1) on my site.
Mask of the input is following:

```
$('#pan').mask('9999  9999  9999  9?999  999', {placeholder:" "});
```

This is for credit card pan so only digits and spaces are acceptable.
When android browser user taps on the input he needs to switch his keyboard to digital.
That's what he does.
But after entering a single digit keyboard switches back to "English letters".

I made an investigation and found out what couses this effect. It's this line in plugin:

```
input.val(buffer.join(''));
```

This plugin fully rewrites the value of an input on each button press.

Can anybody advise a solution of how to deal with this behavior? (i mean how to prevent keyboard from switching to default on input value rewrite)

P.S. Not all phones behave like this. And not all version of browser does.
My test "stand":
HUAWEI P2-6011 (android version 4.1.2)

P.P.S. Please don't suggest  becouse it works for digits only, but i need spaces too. If i switch pattern to something like '^[0-9 ]+$' - problem is not solved.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I'm having the same problem on Android 4.2.  Did you find an answer?

Comment: Facing same problem. Did you find anything?